# How to redirect on reference after admin login

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I have to redirect the admin to /admin/reference instead of /admin/index.

I have changed the LoginController,`protected $redirectTo = '/admin/reference';`.t The same with `RegisterController`, the same with the `VerificationController` and the `RedirectIfAuthenticated` but still no redirection.

LoginController:

```
    protected $redirectTo = '/admin/reference';


    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

RegisterController:
        protected $redirectTo = '/admin/reference';

```
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
```

VerificationController:

```
      protected $redirectTo = '/admin/reference';
```

AdminController:

```
            public function index()
                {
                    return view('admin.index');
                }
```

Authenticate Middleware:

```
    protected function redirectTo($request)
        {
            if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
                return route('login');
            }
        }
```

RedirectIfAuthenthicated:

```
  public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/admin/reference');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

index.blade.php:
This is what is currently shows

```
@extends('admin.layouts.app')

@section('content')
    Willkommen!
@endsection
```

admin.reference.index:This is what i want it to show

```
    @extends('admin.layouts.app')

    @section('title', '| Übersicht Referenzen')

    @section('content')
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading"><h3>Referenzen</h3></div>
                <div class="panel-heading">Seite {{ $references->currentPage() }} von {{ $references->lastPage() }}</div>
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Bilder</th>
                    <th>Priorität</th>
                    <th>Aktionen</th>
                </tr>
                    @foreach ($references as $reference)
                       <tr>
                            <td width="65%">
                                <a href="{{ route('admin.reference.edit',     $reference->id ) }}"><b>{{ $reference->title }}</b>
                            </a><br>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                                @if(!count($reference->images))<span     style="color:#ff0000;font-weight:700;">0</span>@else{{ count($reference->images) }}@endif
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{ $reference->priority }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="{{ route('admin.reference.edit', $reference->id) }}" class="btn btn-info pull-left"
                                    style="margin-right: 3px; display: inline-block;">Edit</a>
                                <div style="display: inline-block;">
                                {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE',     'route' => ['admin.reference.destroy', $reference->id], 'data-item-id' => $reference->id ]) !!}
                                {!! Form::submit('Löschen', ['class' =>  'btn    btn-danger delete-submit','data-item-id' => $reference->id]) !!}
                                {!! Form::close() !!}
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                @endforeach
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                {!! $references->links() !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

I expect after the login to be redirected to /admin/reference instead of /admin/index.

Comment: Share the LoginController!

Comment: i did. the login controller is there as well. just had 5 lines of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected function authenticated()
    {
        if ( Auth::user() ) {
            return redirect('/admin/reference');
        }

        return redirect('/');
    }
```

added a protected function into my LoginController and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on laravel 5.5 but I think this would help you. Try adding this to your login controller

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
if ( $user->isAdmin() ) {// check role
    return redirect('/admin/reference');;
}

 return redirect('/anywhere');
}
```

Comment: i used that code but i had a argument 1 passed error. i changed it to this now though and it worked: